# Opening IE, navigate to URL and get source code in C#

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

I need to open up Internet Explorer with an URL and then read the source code of the document in C#.

Is this possible?

I know you can start processes but how can i navigate to an URL and get the source code?
I have to open it via IE, because the protocol im using to retrieve the page only works in IE.

Thanks!

Comment: The code as in HTML? Use a WebRequest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your requirements there are different techniques:

- `Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "http://www.google.com");` to run IE and then a [`WebCilent.DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) to download the HTML source (2 HTTP requests sent to the server)
- Use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control which allows you to embed IE in a desktop application. It also allows you to retrieve the HTML source code of the webpage to which it navigated.

Answer (score 4):

Following can get you html from a url without opening IE.

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    string html = client.DownloadString(address);
}
```

To open IE for a particular URL you can do :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore", "http://example.com");
```